# Flutter - Firebaser PlatformException handling on UI (ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE, The email address is already in use by another account., null))

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I finalizing the UI to handle some error message in authentication.

I placed catch error in the API for sign up (the same is done for Logging in)

```
signup(User user, AuthNotifier authNotifier) async {
  try{
  AuthResult authResult = await FirebaseAuth.instance
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: user.email, password: user.password)
      .catchError((error) => print(error.code));

  if (authResult != null) {
    UserUpdateInfo updateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
    updateInfo.displayName = user.displayName;

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = authResult.user;

    if (firebaseUser != null) {
      await firebaseUser.updateProfile(updateInfo);

      await firebaseUser.reload();

      print("Sign up: $firebaseUser");

      FirebaseUser currentUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
      authNotifier.setUser(currentUser);
      
    }
  }}catch  (e) {
  print('Failed with error code: ${e.code}');
  print(e.message);}
}
```

The error visibility to user is expected when I added widget triggered by the error message and validation.

```
bool validate() {
    final form = _formKey.currentState;
    form.save();
    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }


  submitForm() {
    if (validate())
    {
try{
    AuthNotifier authNotifier = Provider.of<AuthNotifier>(context, listen: false);
    if (_authMode == AuthMode.Login) {
      login(_user, authNotifier);
    } else if (_authMode == AuthMode.Signup) {
      signup(_user, authNotifier);
      return   Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return SecondPage();
            },
      ),
    );
  }
} catch (e) {
        setState(() {
          _warning = e.message;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  Widget _showAlert() {
    if (_warning != null) {
      return Container(
        color: Colors.amberAccent,
        width: double.infinity,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
              child: Icon(Icons.error_outline),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: AutoSizeText(
                _warning,
                maxLines: 3,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _warning = null;
                  });
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
    return SizedBox(
      height: 0,
    );
  }
```

Despite all implementation to catch error, the errors are not being caught properly in UI. The messages such as PlatformException(ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE, etc..) are not passed on the Showalert widget.

Answer (score 0):

You should throw the error instead of printing it so the try/catch can catch it.

```
void main() async {
  await yourFunc();
}

Future<void> someFuncThrowsError() async {
  throw Error();
}

Future<void> someFuncCaller() async {
   try {
    await someFuncThrowsError().catchError((e) {
      throw e;
    });
  } catch (e) {
    print(e.toString());
    print('try catch');
    rethrow;
  }
}

Future<void> yourFunc() async {
  try {
    await someFuncCaller();
  } catch (e) {
    //set warning
    print('caught');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Edenar, how would you include the message into the UI?

Comment: rethrow it so the try/catch containing the signup call can catch it.